# Spark scala dataframe, parsing complex date into long

Tags: scala, date, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Tried a number of things, but can't seem to figure out how to transform this date format into a long, to nearest millisecond:

```
scala> var df = sc.parallelize(Seq("2020-07-17T17:52:48.758512Z")).toDF("ts")
```

I'd like to do it with an efficent spark scala dataframe transform.  Help?

---

Tried solution below, but not working for me.  Do I need newer version of Spark?

```
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 2.4.6
      /_/

Using Scala version 2.11.12 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_252)

...

scala> var df = sc.parallelize(Seq("2020-07-17T17:52:48.758512Z")).toDF("ts")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [ts: string]

scala> df.withColumn("ts1", to_timestamp(col("ts"), "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS'Z").cast("long")).show(false)
+---------------------------+----+
|ts                         |ts1 |
+---------------------------+----+
|2020-07-17T17:52:48.758512Z|null|
+---------------------------+----+


scala> df.withColumn("ts1", to_timestamp(col("ts"), "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS'Z").cast("double")).show(false)
+---------------------------+----+
|ts                         |ts1 |
+---------------------------+----+
|2020-07-17T17:52:48.758512Z|null|
+---------------------------+----+
```

Comment: could you share  the output format you would expect?

Comment: 1595022768759, includes the millisecond.

Answer (score 2):

Try with `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS'Z` format to parse your timestamp string. Worked for me!

```
df.withColumn("ts1", to_timestamp(col("ts"), "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS'Z").cast("long")).show(false)

+---------------------------+----------+
|ts                         |ts1       |
+---------------------------+----------+
|2020-07-17T17:52:48.758512Z|1595022768|
+---------------------------+----------+
```

Or, you can use the `unix_timestamp` instead of casting as below,

```
df.withColumn("ts1", unix_timestamp(to_timestamp(col("ts"), "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS'Z")))
```

Comment: That's to the nearest second, right?  Is it possible to get it to the nearest millisecond, the SSSS part of the date?